# VueJS - utilizing Vuetable-2 tables package

Tags: vue.js, html-table

I want to use `Vuetable-2` table in my `Vue` components, following the documentation https://www.vuetable.com/guide/getting-started.html#installation, I installed the package using npm `npm install vuetable-2@next --save`, and then exported the component in order to use it:

```
<script setup>
import Vuetable from "vuetable-2";
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <vuetable
            ref="vuetable"
            :fields="['name', 'nickname', 'email', 'gender']"
            :api-mode="false"
            :data="localData"
        ></vuetable>
    </div>
</template>
```

when hovering over the imported package in `vscode`, it says `Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuetable-2'. 'c:/xampp/htdocs/school-system/node_modules/vuetable-2/dist/vuetable-2.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`, when i run the project, i get error in console `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c') vuetable-2.js:1`

the import doesn't seem to work correctly, what could be the problem ? thanks

Comment: It has a Vue 2 requirement.  Are you using Vue 2?

Comment: (2.0+), means Vue 2 or more

Comment: The library hasn't been updated since 2018 before Vue 3 was ever a thing.  If you check the github you can verify that it is [for Vue 2 only](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/blob/next/package.json#L96)